# SQL query to loop on a given data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have data of the following form

```
  ID              Description
-------     ------------------------
83633       Reserves - 1  
83634       Reserves - 2
83635       Reserves - Total
83636       X Reserves  
83637       E Reserves  
83638       Oil 
83639       NGL 
83640       NB Gas  
83641       NU Gas
102195      Proved Reserves - D
102196      Proved Reserves - U
102197      Proved Reserves - Total 
102198      Probable Reserves - Gross
102199      Proved Reserves - G1
102200      Proved Reserves - G2
102201      Proved Reserves - G3
102202      Proved Reserves - G4
102203      Proved Reserves - N1
102204      Proved Reserves - N2
102205      Proved Reserves - N3
102206      Proved Reserves - N4
102207      Probable Reserves - G1
102208      Probable Reserves - G2
102209      Probable Reserves - G3
102210      Probable Reserves - G4
102211      Oil 
102212      NGL 
102213      CNG
102214      Natural Gas
```

I wish to write a query to select Id's that increment by only one. For example if i give the starting `ID=83633` then the query should return the following data

```
  ID              Description
-------     ------------------------
83633       Reserves - 1  
83634       Reserves - 2
83635       Reserves - Total
83636       X Reserves
83637       E Reserves  
83638       Oil 
83639       NGL 
83640       NB Gas  
83641       NU Gas
```

On encountering `ID = 102195` the query must stop executing. Thanks in advance for the help!!

Comment: where id between 83633 and 102195 order by id

what exactly you are looking for ?what if any id in between is deleted,say 83634

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    Description
FROM(
    SELECT 
        ID+1-ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) Col,
        * 
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE ID>=83633
)x WHERE Col=83633
```

Comment: Good answer. You are missing a WHERE ID>=83633 in the inner select however, so you are not hindered by any potential lower IDs. Moreover it may be the case you need a qualifier for * (i.e. YourTable.*). This is necessary at least in Oracle. Don't know about SQL-Server.

Comment: Yes @ThorstenKettner, you are correct! Thanks. In oracle, this query won't work, have to add the column names instead of * or an alias name for table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'While' loop as follows:

```
DECLARE @Temp INT

SELECT @Temp =83633
WHILE(@Temp <=102195)
BEGIN
        PRINT CHAR(@Temp )
        SELECT @Temp = @Temp + 1
END
GO
```

Comment: The next item may not be always `102195`. What if I enter the starting id as `ID=102195`...then the above query won't function.

Comment: First get the count (or MAX ID) from first table and store it in a temporary variable, and then use that in place of 102195.